# Let $f:X \to Y$ be map that for $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood s.t $f$ restricted to that nbdh is an injection. Show that $f$ is an immersion.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f:X \to Y$ be such continous open map that for every $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood such that $f$ restricted to that neighborhood is an injection. Show that $f$ is an immersion

Here are my definitions.

> A map $f$ is an embedding if it’s homeomorphic onto it’s image. That is $f$ is injective, continuous and open

> A map $f$ is an immersion if  for every $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $U_x$ such that $f \mid_{U_x} $ is an embedding.

Since $f$ is continuous, for every $x \in X$ and $U_x$ the map $f \mid_{U_x} : U_x \to f[U_x]$ is continuous and surjective so it’s also injective.

Now it doesn’t generally seem to hold that if $f$ is open the restrictions of $f$ would also be so to finish this I would need to show that $f \mid_{U_x}$ is open?

Let $V \subset X$ be open, then $f \mid_{U_x}[V] = f[U_x] \cap E$ for some $E \subset Y$ that is open. Now doesn’t it follow from the subspace topology that $f[U_x] \cap E$ is open and thus $f \mid_{U_x}$ would be open?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  I think you're assuming that $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous open map, and trying to prove that each $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ such that $f$ restricted to $U_x$ is an immersion.  Please confirm.  This statement certainly isn't true for maps that are merely continuous.  Consider the projection onto the $y$-axis of the graph of $y=x^2$.  There is no neighborhood around $(0,0)$ such that $f$ restricted to that neighborhood is an immersion.

Comment: You gave a "let" but then no conclusion.  It is not clear what you wish to show.

Comment: Sorry... I was writing this on mobile. Corrected @Randall

Comment: The maps are continuous and open and the restriction is an injection. @RobertShore

Answer (score 1):

**Prop #1**: Given any set $A\subseteq X$ define the function $f_A:A\rightarrow Y$ by $f_A:=f|_A$. Then for any $B\subseteq Y$ we have $f_{A}^{-1}(B)=A\cap f^{-1}(B).$

**Proof of Prop #1**: Since $f\equiv f_{A}$ on $A$ we have $$\begin{eqnarray*} f_A^{-1}(B) &=& \{x\in A:f_{A}(x)\in B\} \\ &=& \{x\in A:f(x)\in B\} \\ &=& \{x\in X:x\in A,f(x)\in B\} \\ &=&A \cap f^{-1}(B)\end{eqnarray*}$$

Now to prove your assertion. Take $x\in X$, and find an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $f_{U}:=f|_U$ is an injection. We need to prove $f_{U}$ is a continuous open map.

**Claim #1**: $f_{U}$ is continuous.

**Proof of Claim #1**: Let $V\in \tau_{Y}$ be open. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V)\in \tau_X$ and using **Prop #1** $f_{U}^{-1}(V)=U\cap f^{-1}(V)\in \tau_{U}.$

**Claim #2**: $f_{U}$ is an open map.

**Proof of Claim #2**: Let $A\cap U\in \tau_{U}$. Then $A\in \tau_{X}$ and so $A\cap U\in \tau_{X}$. Because $f$ is open and $f\equiv f_{U}$ on $U$ we have $f_{U}(A\cap U)=f(A\cap U)\in \tau_{Y}$ and $f_U$ is open.